# timepicker change timeFormat without destroying?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am using a timepicker add-on (found here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I have series of timepickers, along with a menu option that allows the user to change the time format.  However, the only way I can get this to work correctly is that I have to run a function that destroys the timepicker and then resets  the defaults:

```
    $("#timeformat").change(function () {
    $(".mytime").timepicker("destroy");
    $(".mytime").timepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    oneLine: true,
    timeFormat: $(this).val()  
});
```

This presents an issue because on all of my timepickers, I am setting the default times independently so they are already filled in, with the option for the user to manually change the times.  When I destroy the timepickers, it also wipes the default times I've added.

Is there a way around this without having to destroy the timepickers so that I can keep my default times when a user changes the format?

Comment: pass the data from the old timepicker to the new one

Comment: Can you tell me more about your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Pass data from the old timepicker

```
$("#timeformat").change(function () {
    $past-time = $(".mytime").val();
    $(".mytime").timepicker("destroy");
    $(".mytime").timepicker({
       controlType: 'select',
       oneLine: true,
       timeFormat: $(this).val();  
    });
    $(".mytime").val($past-time);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I ran an alert on "$(".mytime").val();" and it's empty.  I am setting the default time by using the following:  "$("#timestart").timepicker({
             hour: 8,
             minute: 30
    });"

Comment: I should add that part of the reason the value may be empty is because the default times don't actually show on the input until the user selects the timepicker (second issue I'm working on).